# set rounding off for Double

Tags: java

How to set rounding off with 1.5 , but I know we can do this using 1.6.Please give your guidance.
I want to get double value without round off its decimal like this.
I couldn't use the roundingmode with 1.5.

```
   double d1 = 1234567812342134.45678567;
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".00000");
   df.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
   //df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN); 
   System.out.println(df.format(d1));
```

**Expected output :**
1234567812342134.45678

**Now output :**
1234567812342134.50000

Comment: It's not *at all* clear what you're trying to achieve. Please give more information.

Comment: updated the question please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `double d1 = 1234567812342134.45678567;`

It is too big for `double` to store to that degree of accuracy, if you remove 5 digits from either end you shall get the rounding you're after; your `DecimalFormat` related code is otherwise fine.